# My Xcode unexpectedly closes when I try to use large numbers in it. Any idea why?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, long-integer, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was trying to implement a sieve of Eratosthenes in my Xcode using C++. I gave the limits as 1 and 99999999999. But it just closed without showing if the build had succeeded or not. I thought there was something wrong with my code, and implemented the same with another code from internet. Same thing happened with that too.

Please help me.

Comment: So you hit build, or Xcode just abruptly exited upon you typing the final `9`? What exactly did the code look like?

Comment: You must have discovered a new prime number ;-)

Comment: I hard coded the limits. My code was a direct copy of the one available at geeks 4 geeks.

Comment: And yeah, it abruptly exited as soon as I hit build. After sometime, I tried a few other codes, with most of the ones involving large numbers, like quick sort, merge sort and shell sort same thing happened. As soon as I hit the build button, it exited abruptly.